# (TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly) when pushing a data into a table using python environment

Tags: python, arrays, int, implicit

Age and phone_num are int values rest all are strings. when  trying to push this into a DB using the code below am getting the following error

```
insert_query = "insert into employee.details (name,emp_id,age,contact,address) values('"+name+"','"+emp_id+"',"+age+","+phone_num+",'"+address+"')"
    cursor = connection.cursor
    result = cursor.execute(insert_query)
    print("Table updated successfully ")
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and a [mcve].

Comment: insert_query = "insert into employee.details (name,emp_id,age,contact,address) values ('"+name+"','"+emp_id+"',"+age+","+phone_num+",'"+address+"')"
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Am trying to insert values into a database table using python environment.

Comment: All that information should go in your post, it’s difficult to read and easy to miss comments.

Comment: Will try to improve it next time, am new to this portal so i was not aware about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were getting this error because python cannot combine integers and strings unless they are explicitly converted using `str()`

I assume you are using SQLite3? If so here is the proper syntax for a query.

```py
insert_query = """INSERT INTO employee.details (name, emp_id, age, contact, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""" 

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(insert_query, (name, emp_id, age, phone_num, address))

one_row = cur.fetchone()  # This will only get one row of the data
all_data = cur.fetchall()  # This will get all rows of data in a list of tuples

conn.commit()
conn.close()  # only if this is last db change
```

Templating into your query using a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) will automatically escape strings and prevent [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It will also convert your integers to strings, fixing your error.

Comment: Am using Mysql DB

Comment: @user73388 you have to put all this information in your post as well as a minimal reproducible example. I.E something that we can copy paste to reproduce the error. We are trying our best to help you but we can’t if you don’t read the rules or put any effort into your question

Comment: Soory for this , new to this portal . Will correct everything in the future